# Why are all non-polynomial functions are basically exponents?

Tags: functions, soft-question

There's paucity of really "original" functions in Math. Aside from power functions/ polynomials, really the only other function widely used is exponential.

For example, $\log$ is simply inverse of $\exp$, $\sin$ and $\cos$ (and, by extension, other trig functions) can be obtained using Euler's formula, and so on.

Why is this? Is there any philosophical reason why Mathematics did not come up with other, different basic "building blocks" of functions?

Comment: Don't put the cart before the horse.  The Bessel functions, useful for physics in a cylinder, come from natural differential equations.  They *happen to have* power series expansions, but that's a computational crutch, not a central feature of the functions.  The same holds for the rest of the "second order ODE" functions from physics in the 17th and 18th centuries.

Comment: Exponentials and polynomials seem to have a special place in our notation however. I'd be interested in why that's the case.

Comment: You would be shocked, but power functions are also none other than exponentials in disguise: $x^2=e^{2\ln x}$... :) And Bessel functions, however useful, can be represented by integrals of exponentials combined with some other functions known to be representable via exponentials. This is a plot of an evil mastermind:)

Comment: One special feature shared by exponential and polynomials is that they are eigenfunctions of differential operators, i.e. $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} y= y$ for exponential and $\frac{\mathrm d^n}{\mathrm dx^n} y= 0$ for polynomials of degree $<n$.

Answer (score 3):

I would say that the most widely used functions are simply solutions to differential equations. Consider the following differential equations:

$$y^{(n)} = C$$

$$y' = y$$

$$y'' = y$$

All of these differential equations are relatively simple and the solutions to these equations are $n$th degree polynomials, exponential functions and sum of exponents (including sine and cosine). Furthermore, many "small" changes to these differential equations ($y' = x + y$) produce solutions that are the sum or product of polynomials and exponentials. I recommend that you plug in some [other differential equations](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%27%27+%3D+y+%2B+5y%27%27+%2B+7y%27%27%27%27) that just involve derivatives of $y$ and see how often they involve exponential solutions. (See the comment about eigenvalues above).

I would say that the most common phenomena grow proportionally to their value and are best represented with exponents. If not, they may grow proportionally to their second derivative. There are many other differential equations such as

$$x^2 \frac{d^2 y}{dx^2} + x \frac{dy}{dx} + (x^2 - \alpha^2)y = 0$$

which define the [Bessel Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function) but I would conjecture that this type of relationship is less common than something such as exponential growth. If it was common then it would probably belong to the standard canon of functions. Similarly for the [Airy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_function) function.

The [Gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) is widely used but it is an extension of the factorial which very simple recursive definition which could explain why it pops up so much.

I would like to note that rational functions and logistic functions should be added to the list of "non-polynomial important functions."

Answer (score 1):

> *Is there any philosophical reason why Mathematics did not come up with other, different 
>  basic "building blocks" of functions?*

No. The reasons are practical. There are **almost** no uses in practice for [tetration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration) and other 
 [higher-order operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth's_up-arrow_notation), so exponentiation, which is at its basis a generalization of repeated 
 multiplication, is the last operation of practical interest to humans. [Stirling's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation), for 
 instance, which is helpful for approximating [factorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial) and, by extension, [combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) or 
 [binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient), would be an exception to the rule, and there are perhaps a few others, 
 such as, say, [Bell numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number) and the like. The former is of the order $n^n=~^2n$, and the latter 
 of the order $e^{e^x}$.